# Excel macro to copy from two cells from two sheets in one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

```html
Sub buildtimetable()
Dim FolderName As String
Dim Fname As String
FolderName = "C:\New folder\test"
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
    Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls")
    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)
        With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
    Dim w As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A300000").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Select
Range("K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Activate
         Sheets(1).Rows( _
             Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 & _
             ":" & _
             Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 _
             ).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks(Fname).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Select
Range("K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Activate
         Sheets(1).Rows( _
             Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 & _
             ":" & _
             Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 _
             ).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
' go to the next file in the folder
        Fname = Dir
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Loop
End Sub
```

I am trying to open a file in my directory and copy the value from cell K2 in sheets 2 and 3 to a new workbook that I have open on the desktop. THis code does not work, I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong. Mostly having trouble designating which workbook to select/activate.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  What error do you see?

Comment: It does not copy the cell value from K2 to my other workbook, instead I get an endless row of the same number starting in B2 and continuing until the end of the sheet. Right now I am trying to open the new workbook, paste, save and close. then reopen the old workbook, go to sheet 3 and repeat. but this even sounds horribly inefficient and does not seem to work at all.

Comment: I think if you clean up all of the Select and Activate statements the answer will be clear.  You don't need to select or activate a workbook/sheet/cell to copy from it.  Just use the full command.  For example: `Workbook.Worksheet.Range(...).Copy`

Comment: what goes in the (...) section? and what does the paste command look like? if my file to copy to is named test.xlsx and my opened file is whatever is in the directory (or fname in this case)

Comment: The ... in your case would be "K2" for example.  And the paste command would look the same as the .Paste... that you're using now it's just that the object would be like I said.  And the reason for your problem with the paste is that you're telling it to paste in the entire row.  The object of your paste is currently Workbook.Worksheet.Row.Paste and it should be Workbook.Worksheet.Range.Paste

Comment: so something like: workbook(Fname).Worksheet(2).Range("K2").Copy and then workbook("test.xlsx").worksheet(1).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Comment: Since I am opening up several files where in Range(...) do i designate to paste to the next cell in column? So my line for paste right now is just Workbook("test.xlsx").Worksheet(1).Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Comment: running Workbooks(Fname).Worksheet(2).Range("K2").Copy gives me an obkect does not support this error

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
Sub buildtimetable()
Dim FolderName As String
Dim Fname As String
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim w2 As Worksheet

Set w = Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Sheets(1)

FolderName = "C:\New folder\test\"
    Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls")
    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)
        With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)
            Set w1 = .Sheets(2)
            Set w2 = .Sheets(3)
            
            w1.Range("K2").Copy
            
            w.Range("B" & w.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1).PasteSpecial _
                                                              Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                                                              
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            w2.Range("K2").Copy
    
            w.Range("C" & w.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row + 1).PasteSpecial _
                                                              Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        End With
' go to the next file in the folder
        Fname = Dir
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        .Close
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: that runs to an invalid or unqualified reference error @ .close at the end.

Comment: Sorry.  Move that to just before the `End With` line.

Comment: that loses the error but nothing happens when i hit run

Comment: It's because you have screen updating set to false at the end.

Comment: no i mean nothing appears in the timetable file nor does it even open the file from the directory i think that this is wrong Set w1 = .Sheets(2)
            Set w2 = .Sheets(3) shouldnt i be putting somethign before .sheets?

Comment: Make sure that ScreenUpdating is set to true and EnableAlerts is set to true and check again.  If that does not work, step through the code and see exactly the behavior.  It's next to impossible to troubleshoot these types of problems without the files/folders in question.

Comment: how do i step through?

Comment: missing a slash on the directory file! but now i get error:  method range of object failed on the first paste line w.Range("B" & w.Range("B2").End(xlDown)....

Comment: That means that your used range of cells goes off the bottom of the sheet.  Delete all of the blank rows and try again.

Comment: what do you mean delete all of the blank rows? the workbook i am copying to is already empty.

Comment: I changed xldown to xlup and it worked, but it overwrote the cells when it got to the next file in the directory it did not place it under the last one in the column.

Comment: `xlUp` is finding the first row in the column.  Go to Cell B1 and press Ctrl+<Down Arrow> and see where it stops.  My guess is that it stops somewhere far down the sheet.  You need to delete all empty cells before you start this or xlUp or xlDown will not work.

Comment: the whole sheet is empty it is a brand new file. ctrl down puts me at the bottom of the empty sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this and seems to be working but the copy puts it at the wrong place in the other excel file and it does not copy everything or move down the row properly.

```html
Sub buildtimetable()
Dim FolderName As String
Workbooks.Open ("C:\TimeTable.xlsx")
Dim Fname As String
    
    FolderName = "C:\New folder\test"
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
    Fname = Dir(FolderName & "*.xls")

    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)
    With Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Fname)

    Dim lastrow As Long
  
lastrow = Range("B300000").End(xlUp).Row
'Time

Workbooks(Fname).Worksheets(2).Range("K2").Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("B" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Workbooks(Fname).Worksheets(3).Range("K2").Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("C" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'Max Min value a

Workbooks(Fname).Worksheets(1).Range("O2").Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("D" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Workbooks(Fname).Worksheets(3).Range("N2").Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("E" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'Max Min value b

Workbooks(Fname).Worksheets(2).Range("P2").Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("F" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Workbooks(Fname).Worksheets(3).Range("M2").Copy
Workbooks("TimeTable.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("G" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End With
        
        
' go to the next file in the folder
Fname = Dir
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Loop
End Sub
```